# typecasting in threads code

Tags: c, pthreads

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/samples/join.c

I am looking at the pthreads  code at the link above.

I am not able to understand the type casting that is being done in the code above for variable t and status in BusyWork and main methods.

From man pages for pthread_exit:

**The value pointed to by retval should not be located on the calling thread's stack, since the contents of that stack are undefined after the thread terminates.**

So I guess the type casting in the example is trying to avoid referring memory on the stack of thread that has just terminated. But I find that typecasting quite inconvenient and bizzare. Can someone explain?

Comment: I don't think that typecasting would have anything to do with the storage of the `t` variable. It is also superfluous, since `t` is already of type `void *`...

Comment: I concur with H2C03. The cast is superfluous, but I think you may be confusing a value located "on" the stack of the calling thread vs. a *passed-by-value* parameter *in* the stack. I.e. Returning `&t` (or any of the other stack var addresses) must be avoided, as the resulting `void *` is undefined out of the call-frame of the proc. The *value* of `t` itself is just that, a value, nothing more, and in this case, the same one passed in. At least I believe that is where your disconnect may be.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a thread with pthread_create, your argument is limited to `sizeof(void *)`, you usually use it to pass a pointer to a struct or any other data that may be bigger than the size of argument.

In this example, the argument `long t` have a size smaller than `sizeof(void *)`, so you can simply pass your argument directly to the pthread_create() call.

The explicit cast is made to ensure that if there is any difference between the memory allocated for type (long) or type (void *), it will be fixed by the compiler.

In practice, those cast will do nothing in most platform, but you cannot guarantee that, so you must explicit cast your argument to the correct type before using it.

Resuming: the example is using the type `void *` as a type `long`, and not as a literal pointer, so the variable `status` do not dereference anything.